# How to verify criteria.list is empty?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've created a criteria to retrieve list of items. Although as expected, no result will be returned the if condition does not work.

```
Criteria cre = session.createCriteria(Name.class,"name);
cre.add(Restrictions.eq("name.fname","Alex");
List<Name> names = (List<Name>) cre.list();
```

I used both following 'if' conditions but neither works

```
1) if(names.isEmpty())
       System.err.println("cre is empty"); 

2) if(names != null)
       System.err.println("cre is empty");
```

Comment: The first one is the one you want. The returns list will never be null. If the list is not empty, then it means your query does return something. Print its content, and you'll see.

Comment: @JBNizet none of the if conditions work, even if the list is empty isEmpty does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `size()` of the list. If the list's size is 0, it is empty.

```
if(names.size() == 0){
//it is empty
}

if(names.size() > 0){
//it is **not** empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way

```
cre.list().isEmpty()
```